# How to find Spring version in Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: java, spring

I can find which Java version Spring Tool Suite is using in Preferences. Where do I go to find the Spring version it is using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest is the maven/gradle configuration file. None of the IDE menus or Debug configurations state it explicitly

Comment: What is the file name? Under Maven Dependencies, I see spring-aop, spring-beans, spring-expression and they have version 4.3.9.

Comment: For maven is pom for gradle build.grdle

Comment: How to configure this in maven pom.xml?

Answer (score 5):

Check the version of spring with this code !

```
import org.springframework.core.SpringVersion;

public class VersionChecker
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("version: " + SpringVersion.getVersion());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried with checking my pom.xml which did not had any information about the SpringVersion used.

However with the SpringVersion.getVersion() method i was able to figure out it was 5.2.5